# MySQL - Inserting a row using a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert a row using a `Foreign Key` from another table, but I'm unsure how to do it.

My Query is

```
INSERT INTO customers(
    Customer_Name,
    Address,
    Postal_Code,
    Phone,
    Create_Date,
    Created_By,
    Last_Update,
    Last_Updated_By,
    Division_ID //This is the foreign key. It's the Primary key for my first_level_divisions Table
) VALUES (
    'Alex',
    '123 Sesame Street',
    '12345',
    '123-456-7891',
    '1986-10-22',
    'Alex',
    '1986-10-22 09-30-14',
    'Alex',
    5 //Foreign key I want to insert
)
```

The other query would be

`SELECT Division_ID FROM first_level_divisions WHERE division = 'Alberta'`

How would I combine these two queries?

I've tried adding it as the last value but that doesn't quite work

```
) VALUES (
    'Alex',
    '123 Sesame Street',
    '12345',
    '123-456-7891',
    '1986-10-22',
    'Alex',
    '1986-10-22 09-30-14',
    'Alex',
    SELECT Division_ID FROM first_level_divisions WHERE division = 'Alberta'
)
```

Comment: Parentheses needed, like `(SELECT... 'Alberta')`.

Comment: Or do `INSERT INTO t SELECT 'Alex', ..., Division_ID FROM first_level_divisions WHERE division = 'Alberta'`.

Comment: Ah got it, thanks!

Comment: @jarlh: Your comments would make a good answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select needs parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO customers(
    ...
    Division_ID //This is the foreign key. It's the Primary key for my first_level_divisions Table
) VALUES (
    'Alex',
    ... ,
    (SELECT Division_ID FROM first_level_divisions WHERE division = 'Alberta')
)
```

Or do a SELECT with INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO customers(
    Customer_Name,
    Address,
    Postal_Code,
    Phone,
    Create_Date,
    Created_By,
    Last_Update,
    Last_Updated_By,
    Division_ID //This is the foreign key. It's the Primary key for my first_level_divisions Table
)
SELECT
    'Alex',
    '123 Sesame Street',
    '12345',
    '123-456-7891',
    '1986-10-22',
    'Alex',
    '1986-10-22 09-30-14',
    'Alex',
    Division_ID
FROM first_level_divisions
WHERE division = 'Alberta'
```